# How to return all the tags from a specific vocabulary for the current node

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am trying to return all tags from a vocabulary but the code below keeps giving me error.

```
$vid = 1;  
$nid = arg(1);

$getterms = db_query('SELECT t.tid, t.* FROM {taxonomy_term_data} t INNER JOIN {taxonomy_index} r ON r.tid = t.tid WHERE t.vid = :vid AND r.nid = :node_nid ORDER BY weight', array(':vid' => $vid, ':node_nid' => $nid->nid));
```

I am getting 2 errors:

- Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval() ...
- Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DatabaseStatementBase could not be converted to string in eval() ...

Answer (score 1):

`arg()` returns a string so `$nid` is not an object. You're currently adding your `:node_nid` database condition with a value of `$nid->nid`, when you should just be using `$nid`:

```
$vid = 1;  
$nid = arg(1);

// Updated as per comments below
$sql = 'SELECT t.name FROM {taxonomy_term_data} t INNER JOIN {taxonomy_index} r ON r.tid = t.tid WHERE t.vid = :vid AND r.nid = :node_nid ORDER BY weight';
$args = array(':vid' => $vid, ':node_nid' => $nid);

$terms = db_query($sql, $args)->fetchCol();
$comma_separated = implode(', ', $terms);
```

If you want to load the node object related to the current path then you can use `menu_get_object()`; then you can access the nid as part of the object:

```
$node = menu_get_object();
$nid = $node->nid;
```

But I suspect that will be overkill as you only really need the `$nid`, and not the full node object for your query.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Is there any way I could extract the tags without having to write a query? I'd like to return the values as a string separated by comma. Hope am not asking too much :)

Comment: There are other ways (using the Field API functions) but you'll end up with more complicated code for no real benefit (unless there is a radical shift in the way the taxonomy module stores its term/node index in the future, which I think is unlikely). What you're doing is perfectly valid and I think the best/easiest way to do this. I'll update the code in the answer to show you the shortest way to do this :)